# Use Size Classes или Simulated Metrics?

Tags: xcode

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, в чем разница. 
С новым Xcode 6 вышла такая функция, как Size Classes, так вот если отключить ее, то есть нажать на кнопку Use Size Classes, то view станет привычной формы. Но можно этого же добиться и при помощи свойств view, если в Simulated Metrics выставить размер дисплея. Так вот в чем разница?

Если выбрать дисплей через Simulated Metrics, то при создании связи между кнопкой и вторым контроллером появляется действие show, а если убрать Use Size Classes, то этого действия нет. Почему?

Случай с Simulated Metrics:

[image]

Comment: В общем, если кому интересно, то в iOS 8 при выборе Use Size Classes появляется "show" и "present modally" вместо "Push", поэтому старые параметры помечены как нежелательные (deprecated). Грубо говоря, Show это переименованный Push.

Comment: Считаю даный вопрос полезным, и рекомендую оформить его, как ответ, с возможностью его дополнения.

Answer (score 1):

Simulated metrics это инструмент для просмотра того, как ваш интерфейс будет выглядеть на реальном устройстве. Изменение этих настроек не влияет на само приложение.

Size Classes - решение для разработки одного сториборда, который будет работать на всех устройствах (iPad и iPhone).

Show segue доступен в рамках Size Classes и является одним из переходов, которые так же адаптируются к размеру экрана устройства, на котором запущено приложение.